# I need help on my palindrome programm in python

Tags: python, palindrome

This is my code currently:

```
  def main():
        list1 = [(x) for x in input()]
        if (list1 == list1.reverse()):
            print("The sentence is a palindrome.")
        else:
            print("The sentence is not a palindrome.")

    main()
```

And it doesn't work. I've made the following adjustments when I found them on the forums and it worked:

```
def main():
    list1 = [(x) for x in input()]
    if (list1 == list1[::-1]):
        print("The sentence is a palindrome.")
    else:
        print("The sentence is not a palindrome.")

main()
```

My question is, why doesn't the first version work?
It always prints: The sentence is not a palindrome.

Comment: `list.reverse()` returns `None` because the list is reversed in place.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: `reversed()` returns an iterator, and equality won't test the contents, only if they are the same object (even `reversed(l) == reversed(l)` is `False` as they are two separate iterators).

Comment: `L.reverse` reverses the list in place.  If you try to assign it to a variable, you get `None`.

Comment: `list1.reverse()` is not returning any list, it is just reversing the list, you need to do `list2 = list1[:]` and then `list2.reverse()` and then compare with `list1 == list2`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`list1.reverse()` works in-place. It reverses `list1` and returns `None`, so you're comparing a list to `None` and it's always `False`...

The second code returns a reversed *copy* of `list1` as a `list` so both lists are compared and it works.

Note: another trap would be to compare with `list1 == reversed(list1)`. That would work in python 2, but not in python 3 since `reversed` has been turned into an iterable.

Aside: don't do `list1 = [(x) for x in input()]` but just `list1 = list(input())`

(or as some nice commenter suggested, work directly with `str` type, no need to convert to strings at all, `[::-1]` operation also applies on strings, so just change to `list1 = input()` in your second code snippet)

Comment: ok, done! I just don't want to "steal" ideas from others (I would never have converted the strings to list myself, just been misled by OP code :))

Comment: yes, so if people who don't like you read this, they will think highly of you anyway :)